# why using echo is replacing old text in .txt file?

Tags: windows, echo, batch-file

I want to use echo to add data into a text file progressively. I wrote a small batch code as follows:

```
@echo off
echo >text.txt
set DllCopier_d=./DllCopier

echo %DATE:~04%>text.txt
echo %TIME:~0,5%>text.txt

echo %~dp0%>text.txt
```

When I look at text.txt at the end, i found only one line:

```
C:\omsstest_automation\win32\
```

Which is result of last line.
Why is the "echo" resulting into replacing previous contents of text.txt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`>` means create a new file with these contents (replace the old if it exists), `>>` means append or create a new file if none already exists.

So to spell out the answer to your question, replace subsequent usages of `>` after the very first one with `>>`.